# How to fetch data from Wordpress database tabe wp_postMeta with PHP custom query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am developing a custom PHP based website and attaching it with WordPress database, I want to fetch data from wp_postMeta, with custom PHP not with WordPress get_post_meta.

The major issue I am facing is to convert multidimensional array and displaying record actually I don't know about that how to convert and display .

See the picture please 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EubvG.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have already the query but you can't convert this serialized array into a PHP array? Just use the PHP `unserialize()` function. Take a look at the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

`unserialize()` converts this:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:12:"Sample array";i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:5:"Apple";i:1;s:6:"Orange";}}
```

into this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sample array
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apple
            [1] => Orange
        )

)
```

In your case it could be something like this.. really easy:

```
$array = unserialize( $queried_data );
```

Comment: waeooo thanks for your such a valuable answer exactly what i was looking for . so nice of you and many many thanks for helping me ..

Comment: yeah, glad I could help! :-)

Comment: i more elaborated the answer to display data normally  :               `$array = unserialize( $queried_data ); 
                    $arry_size=sizeof($array);
     for ($x = 0; $x < $arry_size; $x++) {
       //print_r($array);
                     
     foreach($array[$x] as $test){
      echo $test."<br><br>";
      }
      }`

Answer (score 0):

It is actually serialzed data.To parse this data you have to use maybe_unserialize function of wordpress and to get meta_value of a meta_key use get_post_meta('post_id','meta_key',true).This will give you meta_value of a single meta_key.In your case you can do it like this..

```
$meta_value = get_post_meta('post_id','recipe_instructions',true);

$array = maybe_unserialize($meta_value);
```

Then you can get your value from array.

Comment: thanks for your kind reply but i am not woking in wordpress i an writing my own php code. soo get_post_meta is not going to help me :(